# .NET Resource File in different project: How to modify post build?

Tags: asp.net, resources, localization, internationalization, resx

I have a ASP.NET website that references another project with contains as resx file. This file is currently set as an "Embedded Resource" and "Do not copy" to the output directory (although I can change these if need be).

My question is what do I need to do so that once the website has been deployed my coworkers in the Support Department can modify the resource strings?

For example, is there compile time options I can set on the resx file so that it is deployed in a human readable manner? Is there instead a tool they can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Resx files are compiled into the assembly.

Here is some information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f(v=VS.90).aspx